# CocoaPods not linking libraries

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode7, static-linking

i recently started using CocoaPods to manage dependencies in my existing ios project.  i am using Xcode 7.1.1 on a Mac running OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan).

the problem is that i seem to still have to explicitly link the frameworks in the Link Binary with Libraries section of the Build phases, or i get error messages to the effect that "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 ... i get a number of these errors for classes defined in the CocoaPods-managed dependencies.  if i explicitly add the relevant frameworks in the Pods project in the Link Binary with Libraries section of my target, everything works, but from my understanding, this should not be necessary.

here's the podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '7.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

workspace 'myproject'

def shared_pods
  pod 'ParseUI'
  pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
end

target 'myproject' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'myprojectTests' do
  shared_pods
  pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
end
```

i'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that i added pod mgmt to an existing project.  i've tried different Podfile configurations, i've tried deleting and reinstalling, and nothing has worked so far...the only reliable solution to prevent the errors is to explicitly link the relevant frameworks that are in the Pods directories.

any help much appreciated

Comment: just type in your terminal 
`pod --version` and see if Pod actually exists? With the latest update we have to reinstall pods

Comment: 0.39.0 ...all the frameworks are there in the pod project, libPods-myproject.a is listed in the Link Binary with Libraries section, etc etc...the Pods do exist...it's the frameworks in the Pod directories that i'm linking to explicitly to make it all work...but again, why?

Comment: 1) Were you using Crashlytics before switching to Cocoapods? If so, perhaps you did not convert the project properly. 2) Remove everything ion your podfile and only leave the text for the pods you are using   pod 'ParseUI’, pod 'ParseCrashReporting’, pod 'Fabric’, pod 'Crashlytics' and then run ‘pod install’ from the command line. This second suggestion is to just eliminate the extra config info you have in the podfile to see if that’s the issue. Before running ‘pod install’ you might also manually remove the .xcworkspace and Pods directory as those will get rebuilt anyway.

Comment: i'll try...i've done all that already once before, but i'll start clean again and post once i've done it

Comment: ps. i was using Crashlytics prior to switching to CocoaPods, and when they migrated to Fabric i updated as per their instructions.  but the linker errors are not specific to any one framework, i get them for classes from all the frameworks, i just didn't list them all...the Crashlytics one was the first on the list

Comment: We are having this problem across several machines. The Pods are not showing up as Targets in the Pods Project. We think it is related to OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). Does not appear to be related to the Xcode version, as we are running Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 but both are having problems, and were not having problems prior to OSX10.11

Comment: thanks so much for letting me know.  i've been banging my head against this, trying repeatedly to figure out what step in the process was the problem.  for now, the solution of just explicitly linking the framework in the Pods directory from my app target Build Phases seems to work, but i was concerned that the configuration was still not correct. i'll just proceed that way for the time being until a fix can be found. where can i check to see whether/when this is resolved?

Comment: My project uses external .xcconfig files. When I ran `pod install` it told me to add a reference to the Pod .xcconfig files in my related .xcconfig files. I added those to the end and all my linking problems (same as yours) went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the libraries where compiled fine, but where not found when linking.

In my Podfile (cocoapod version 1.2.1):

```
  abstract_target 'Global' do
    pod 'pod-name', '~> 1.0,0', :configurations => ['Alpha', 'Release']
    pod 'pod-nme2', :configurations => ['Release']

    target 'MyTarget' do
    end
  end
```

The problem was that when i checked the schema that the target was using to compile the code, the configuration used on run, etc was 'Debug' not 'Alpha' as stated on the Podfile under configurations.

When linking the App, it would fail with missing ALL of the pod included libraries!

"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"